# Cannot SCP file to AWS using boto

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm trying to automate some uploading with python to my AWS EC2 server. I cannot get the `ssh_client.put_file()` to work. It either keeps giving me either `IOERROR: Failire` or `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file`

Any ideas as to what I'm missing? Can this ssh_client not be used to scp upload?

```
import boto
import boto.ec2
from boto.manage.cmdshell import sshclient_from_instance
import argparse

#Parse input
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Upload and train images for detection')
parser.add_argument('path_to_key', help='Path to Pem key')
parser.add_argument('path_to_tar', help='Path to positives.tar')
args = parser.parse_args()
args_keypath = args.path_to_key
args_tarpath = args.path_to_tar

# Connect to your region of choice
    print "Connecting to server..."
    access_key = ""
    secret_access_key = ""
    conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key)

    print "Connecting to instance..."
    # Connect to an existing instance
    reservations = conn.get_all_instances(['i-c8aab576'])
    instance = reservations[0].instances[0]

    # Create an SSH client for our instance
    #    key_path is the path to the SSH private key associated with instance
    #    user_name is the user to login as on the instance (e.g. ubuntu, ec2-user, etc.)
    print "Creating CommandShell..."
    key_path = args_keypath
    ssh_client = boto.manage.cmdshell.sshclient_from_instance(instance,
                                               key_path,
                                               host_key_file='~/.ssh/known_hosts',
                                               user_name='ubuntu')

    status, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.run('ls -al')
    print(status)
    print(stdout)
    print(stderr)

    #Upload positives - WELL THIS ISN'T WORKING
    print "Uploading file..."
    local_filepath = args_tarpath
    remote_filepath = "~/Sharing/"
    ssh_client.put_file("/home/willem/.ssh/test.txt", "/home/ubuntu/Sharing/")
    #ssh_client.put_file(local_filepath, remote_filepath)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have ssh login access you can use the .pem and run the command locally, my solution was:

Create the server by creating the reservation:

```
reservation = conn.run_instances(my_AMI,
        key_name=my_key,
        instance_type='c4.xlarge',
        security_group_ids=security_group,
        placement='us-east-1d')

instance = reservation.instances[0]
print colored("Instance IP: %s" % instance.ip_address, 'yellow')
```

Then later I could scp the file:

```
instance_IP = instance.ip_address
os.system('scp -i %s %s ubuntu@%s:~/Sharing' % (key_path, args_tarpath, instance_IP) )
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution: specify the file name in the destination path as well. `Boto` in turn uses the `paramiko` module in which `sftp.put` requires the file name to be specified.